# Sbt not found object. But this object is a package

Tags: scala, sbt

I faced with problem of configuring build.sbt files. In my project I have 2 separate modules. Each module is an sbt project. In my build sbt file of the main module I have such:

```
lazy val pluginsTest = ProjectRef(file("../plugins-test"), "pluginsTest")
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(pluginsTest)
```

So for IDE everything is OK,I can import classes from plugins-test module for example  `import pluginsTest.example.Test`, but while I'm trying to compile this project from root module using command prompt it says that:

```
 not found: object pluginsTest
[error] import pluginsTest.example.Test
```

Has anyone faced with this problem?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE

```
D:.
├───.idea
│   ├───libraries
│   └───modules
├───plugins-test
│   ├───.idea
│   │   ├───libraries
│   │   └───modules
│   ├───app
│       └───pluginsTest
│           └───example
│

├───root
    ├───.idea
    │   └───modules
    ├───app
        └───org
            └───root
                   └───services
                       └───common
                           ├───dao
                           ├───main
                           ├───model
                           └───utils
```

`.`

Comment: What is the folders structure? Why do you refer to `../plugins-test`?

Comment: @laughedelic the folder structer is :
`test(just a folder for whole project)                                                                
     ->plugins-test (here lies my Test class)                                                       
     ->root( here my classes which using`   
And I'm trying to compile from root

Comment: I don't get it. Run `tree -L 2` in the root folder of your project and paste output in the question (edit it, don't paste it in the comments)

Comment: @laughedelic Done

Comment: Problem still exist

Comment: I tried a similar setup and couldn't reproduce the problem, it worked fine. You should provide more details: full build.sbt, where it's located, source defining `pluginsTest.example.Test`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that root module used  **.enablePlugins(PlayScala)** when plugins module not. When I added .enablePlugins(PlayScala) in plugins module the issue was resolved.